# Open PDF file and press page down key - Robot Framework

Tags: python, pdf, robotframework

Need solution  for the below requirement. 
I want open the pdf file 'Report.pdf' and go to 2nd page by pressing 'Page Down' key and take screenshot.Using WhiteLibrary.

```
Launch Application    D:\\EDI_Business_Report\\Resources\\Report.pdf
Attach Window    Report.pdf
WhiteLibrary.Press Special Key    PAGEDOWN
```

but getting error on  Attach Window as

> AutomationException: Couldn't find window with title Report.pdf in
>   process 10004, after waiting for 30.0 seconds    at
>   TestStack.White.Factory.ChildWindowFactory.WaitTillFound(Func`1 find,
>   String message)    at
>   TestStack.White.Factory.WindowFactory.CreateWindow(String title,
>   Process process, InitializeOption option, WindowSession windowSession)
>   at TestStack.White.Application.GetWindow(String title,
>   InitializeOption option)    at
>   TestStack.White.Application.GetWindow(String title)

and without attach window

```
Launch Application    D:\\EDI_Business_Report\\Resources\\Report.pdf
WhiteLibrary.Press Special Key    PAGEDOWN
```

error as

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Keyboard'

Please help!! Thanks!!

Comment: have you installed GUI inspection tool as mentioned in the doc?
Windows 10 SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk